# I am trying to understand some machine learning terminology. What is the difference between learning parameters, hyperparameters, and structure?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to understand some machine learning terminology: parameters, hyperparameters, and structure -- all used in a Bayes-net context. 1) In particular, how is structure different than parameters or hyperparameters. 2) What does parameterize mean? Thanks.

Comment: As stands the question is off-topic. Try stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

In general (however exact definition may vary across authors/papers/models):

- structure - describes how elements of your graph/model are connected/organized, thus it is usually a generic description of how information flows. Often it is expressed as a directed graph. On the level of structure you often omit details like models details. Example: logistic regression model consists of an input node and output node, where output node produces P(y|x).
- parametrization - since a common language in Bayesian (and whole ML) approach is a language of probability many models are expressed in terms of probabilities / other quantities which are a nice mathematical objects, but cannot be anyhow implemented/optimized/used. They are just abstract concepts. Parametrization is a process of taking such abstract object and narrowing down the space of possible values to a set of functions which are **parametrized** (usually by real-valued vector/matrices/tensors). For example, our P(y|x) of logistic regression can be **parametrized** as a linear function of x through `P(y|x) = 1/(1 + exp(-<x, w>))` where `w` is a real-valued vector of **parameters**.
- parameters - as seen above - are elements of your model, introduced during parametrization, which are usually **learnable**. Meaning, that you can provide reasonable mathematical ways of finding best values of them. For example in the above example `w` is a parameter, learnable during probability maximization, using for example steepest descent method (SGD).
- hyperparameters - these are values, very similar to parameters, but for which you cannot really provide nice learning schemes. It is usually due to their non-continuos nature, often alternating the structure. For example, in a neural net, a hyperparameter is number of hidden units. You cannot differentiate through this element, so SGD cannot really learn this value. You have to set it apriori, or use some meta-learning technique (which is often extremely inefficient). In general, distinction between parameter and hyperparameter is very fuzzy and depending on the context - they change assigment. For example if you apply genetic algorithm to learn hyperparameters of the neural net, these hyperparameters of the neural net become parameters of the model being learned by GA.

Answer (score 1):

**STRUCTURE**

The structure, or topology, of the network should capture qualitative relationships between variables.In particular, two nodes should be connected directly if one affects or causes the other, with the arc indicating the direction of the effect.

[image: Structure]

Lets consider above example, we might ask what factors affect a patient’s chance of
having cancer? If the answer is “Pollution and smoking,” then we should add arcs
from Pollution and Smoker to Cancer. Similarly, having cancer will affect the patient’s
breathing and the chances of having a positive X-ray result. So we add arcs
from Cancer to Dyspnoea and XRay. The resultant structure is shown in above figure.

**Structure terminology and layout**

In talking about network structure it is useful to employ a family metaphor: a node is a parent of a child, if there is an arc from the former to the latter. Extending the metaphor, if there is a directed chain of nodes, one node is an ancestor of another if
it appears earlier in the chain, whereas a node is a descendant of another node if it
comes later in the chain. In our example, the Cancer node has two parents, Pollution and Smoker, while Smoker is an ancestor of both X-ray and Dyspnoea. Similarly, Xray is a child of Cancer and descendant of Smoker and Pollution. The set of parent nodes of a node X is given by Parents(X).

By convention, for easier visual examination of BN structure, networks are usually laid out so that the arcs generally point from top to bottom. This means that the BN “tree” is usually depicted upside down, with roots at the top and leaves at the bottom!

Answer (score -1):

To add to the answer of lejlot, I would like to spend some words on the term "parameter".

For many algorithms, a synonym for paratemer is `weight`. This is true for most linear models, where a weight is a coefficient of the line describing the model. In this case `parameters` is used only for the parameters of the learning algorithm and this may be a bit confusing when moving to other kinds of ML algorithms. Also, contrary to what lejlot said, these parameters may not be that abstract: often they have a clear meaning in terms of effect on the learning process. For example, with SVMs, parameters may weight the importance of misclassifications.

Comment: My answer never claimed parameters are abstract. I claimed that abstract objects are used before parametrization. Your last sentence, however, incorecctly merges two objects - weights which are parameters of SVM model (parameters) and loss weights (like "sample weights" or "class weights") which have nothing to do with parameters.

Comment: No, I was talking about for example the C parameter or the common Vapnik SVM. Anyway, as I said, there's a deep difference in terminology so maybe you misunderstood.

Comment: C is hyperparameter in auch terminology.